# Which dtype performs better when training a randomforest in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was trying to train a `randomforest` classifier in python. However, in my original `pandas.dataframe`, there are **float64, object, datetime64, int64 and bool** `dtypes`(nearly all kinds of dtypes allowed in pandas).

- Is it necessary to convert a **bool** to **float** or **int**?
- For a **two-value object** column, should I convert it to **bool**, **int**, or **float**? Which one would perform better? Or does it not matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't you tried `%timeit` yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly all scikit-learn estimators will convert input data to float before running the algorithm, regardless of the original types in the array. This holds for the random forest implementation.

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp! A following question: if I have a two-value(A/B value) object(string) variable, do I have to convert it to float? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Yes – take a look at [Encoding Categorical Features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) in the scikit-learn documentation. Note that Random Forests is one of the few algorithms where true categorical features can (in theory) be handled very naturally without tricks like one-hot encoding. Unfortunately, the sklearn implementation is not currently designed to handle data in this form.

Comment: Appreciate! @jakevdp